# How to use Html.BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.beginform

Can you help me interpret this piece of code? What happens after the user clicks Log In?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) 
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>Log in Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>            
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</fieldset>   
}
```

Btw, could not find google documentation on Html.BeginForm at all.

Comment: It just renders the HTML Form tag, the button submits the form, hence the "submit" type. The `using` clause ensures that dispose is called, which renders the close tag. IMO this is an abuse of the language feature, but it is what it is.

Comment: More importantly, what is "new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }"?? Does it submit to the returnURL? <-- which I assume targets a controller function.

Comment: *Btw, could not find google documentation on Html.BeginForm at all.*. First result for "beginform": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: That's FormExtensions.BeginForm, I'm looking for Html.BeginForm and its razor!

Comment: It's the same thing. `Html` is just a `HtmlHelper` object. `BeginForm` is a `HtmlHelper` extension method defined in the `FormExtensions` class.

Comment: oh.. you got me this time. But never again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is submitted to the same URL that rendered it.

As specified in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470793%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), the overload used is `BeginForm(this HtmlHelper helper, object routeValues)`, so the value of `ReturnUrl` will be passed as a route value. What happens to that value depends on the application's routes - typically it will be appended to the request URL as a query string parameter.

Try implementing the view and examining the rendered markup.